# PHP form token help needed

Tags: php, forms, token

I have an issue that i'm hoping someone will be able to assist with. 
I'm trying to implement a token system (using php) but for some reason it keeps failing.

Here's the code that I place in the  of my HTML form (i've also tried placing the code within the form tags)

//-------------------------------------------------

```
<?php
 session_start();
$form_token = uniqid();
$_SESSION['form_token'] = $form_token;
?>
```

//------------------------------------------------------

I also have a hidden field on the form

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="<?php echo $form_token; ?>" />
```

//----------------------------------------------------------

When  the form is sumitted the following script is run:

```
<?php
 session_start();
if(isset($_POST['sumbitcheck'])) {
include('connect.php'); 
    }

if ($_POST['form_token'] !== $_SESSION['token'])
        {
    echo("Invalid Submission");        
        }

if($_POST['form_token']== $_SESSION['form_token'])
        {
     echo("Accees");
        }

?>
```

//--------------------------------------------

For some reason it echos 'invalid submission' and the match never =True Can anyone help?

Many thanks,

Comment: are you sure uniqid() is returning anything valid?

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$_POST['form_token'] !== $_SESSION['token']
```

should be:

```
$_POST['form_token'] !== $_SESSION['form_token']
```

This is because your submitting the hidden field with the name `form_token`, not `token`.

If you wanted to, you could do this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $form_token; ?>" />
```

In which case, your current code would work.

Answer (score 0):

Its because this ...

```
if ($_POST['form_token'] !== $_SESSION['token'])
```

needs to be this...

```
if ($_POST['form_token'] !== $_SESSION['form_token'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
if ($_POST['form_token'] !== $_SESSION['token'])
```

To this:

```
if ($_POST['form_token'] !== $_SESSION['form_token'])
```

Also, check out the manual for the uniqid() function. It is NOT supposed to be used for security purposes.